# JQuery - Clickable div - absolute beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my entire DIV to be clickable, looked-up on the web some solutions, including the one below...but can't achieve desired result..

Here is  the script that i included in the header of my HTML file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<script>
$(".clickable").click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr("data-href");
window.location.href = href;
 });
</script>
```

and my DIV code:

```
    <div class="my_account_container">
    <span class="my_account_title">Collections

    <div class="my_account_sub_container clickable" data-href="http://www.google.com">
        <span class="my_account_sub_container_title">My subscriptions</span>
    <div class="my_account_counts_container">
        <span class="my_account_counts_text">12</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

But I can'y make it work !  thanks in advance for helpI

Comment: Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function() { .... })` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Rmy33/

Comment: Would you mind showing  the entire code wrapped (again  it is literally my first day with Jquery)

Comment: like this:
``$(document).ready(function(){
$(".clickable").click(function() {

   var href = $(this).data("href");
   window.location = href;

 });
});``

Comment: If you're new to jQuery, spend some time on http://learn.jquery.com and then search http://api.jquery.com for questions about specific methods.

Comment: OK just seen your fiddle, that's the solution ! thx heaps, just need to remove now the "working!" pop up!

Comment: thanks both, will spend some time checking links, solution works well

Answer (score 0):

Changed $("clickable") to $(".clickable")

$('#clickable') would be equal to id='clickable'

$('.clickable') would be equal to class='clickable'

Try

```
  $(function(){
      $(".clickable").click(function () {
           var href = $(this).attr("data-href");
           window.location.href = href;
      });
  });
```

Comment: thanks but even with the dot it wont work ..

Comment: Cheers Donal, i used $(document).ready(function () { as mentioned above and worked well